# Object assignment versus referencing

Tags: php, oop, class, object

I've found the following example on [PHP Classes and Objects: The Basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php), but I can't understand what's going on in the background.

There is a statement:

> When assigning an already created instance of a class to a new variable, the new variable will access the same instance as the object that was assigned. This behavior is the same when passing instances to a function. A copy of an already created object can be made by cloning it.

I assume this is states that object are passed by reference by default, so one should [`clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) it, if a real copy is intended to be made. (<strike>There is neither shallow-copy in PHP.</strike> Yes, there is a `clone` by default.)

Consider the following example (copied from the above link):

```
<?php

$instance = new SimpleClass();

$assigned   =  $instance;
$reference  =& $instance;

$instance->var = '$assigned will have this value';

$instance = null; // $instance and $reference become null

var_dump($instance);
var_dump($reference);
var_dump($assigned);

?>
```

As has been told there, this outputs the following:

```
NULL
NULL
object(SimpleClass)#1 (1) {
   ["var"] => string(30) "$assigned will have this value"
}
```

I don't understand.

If `$assigned = $instance;` is an assignment by reference (alias) on objects by default, than why `$assigned` still is an object of `SimpleClass` that holds the `$var` property with that `string`, while the `NULL` was assigned to `$instance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's misleading to say that `$assigned = $instance` is an assignment by reference. You can better think of it as if `$instance` were a pointer: it has value (not reference) semantics, although many copies of it can point to the same object.

On the other hand, `$reference  =& $instance` does create an alias: whatever happens to one of the variables is also immediately visible when the other is examined.

Comment: I'd emphasise the work __point__ $instance = new SimpleClass(); create an instance of SimpleClass; but $instance is a __reference pointer__ to that class object, it isn't the class object itself

Comment: @MarkBaker: Edited the answer a bit, but I 'm still not too happy with the wording (need coffee perhaps...).

Comment: So, `$assigned` pointer is a copy of `$instance` pointer, which are different pointers pointing the same memory. As `$reference` is an alias. I think the key point I was mislead by the part: `$instance=null;`. This only sets the pointer to point "nowhere", while the data is still in the memory intact having `$assigned` point at it?

Comment: @Dyin: In one word yes (although it doesn't technically change the value of the pointer; PHP has dynamic typing so it changes the type of the variable to something else).

Comment: These things are far away from clearance in PHP and in the documentation. At these points I come up losing my patient every time. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between object references and variable references:

Object references are in fact *object identifiers*, stored as *value* of a variable, the objects itself are stored in a separate table, independent of variables.